# Excluding specific nodes from qsub command in sge

Tags: cluster-computing, nodes, qsub, sungridengine

Using SGE I can exclude a node called "testnode" with the option:

$ -l h=!testnode

However, on the cluster I am using the nodes I want to exclude have names like:

allen-291-19.local
allen-117-22.local
etc.

So my question is: Is there a way to exclude all nodes with names beginning with allen, regardless of what comes afterwards? Can this be extended to apply to multiple such nodes? (e.g. ALSO exclude all nodes whose names begin with "bob").

Answer (score 3):

```
qsub -l 'h=!allen*'
```

Should do the trick.  The syntax is defined in the sge_types man page under MATCHING TYPES.